# intro to python: using strings, am I on the right track?

Tags: python

I am brand new to programming and I am wanting to know if I am on the right track.  My task is as follows:

> Write Python script that will, when run, prompt the user to “Enter
>   shape:” so that input variable (entered from the screen) is a string
>   which can be: square, rectangle, triangle, circle or pentagon. Then
>   use if, elif, and else commands to analyze which shape has been
>   entered. The output should be a print on the screen “You entered
>   shape: ” Please note: in order to input string variable, you may use
>   command raw_input instead of input.

My code is:

```
which_shape = int(raw_input("Enter shape (1-5): "))
shape = ['square', 'rectangle', 'triangle', 'circle', 'pentagon']

if 1<= which_shape <= 5:
    print("You entered shape, ") , shape[which_shape - 1]
else:
    print("Shape was not found in list")
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is asking by *"analyze the string using if, elif, and else"*.

Comment: Shouldn't you input a string, instead of int?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using python, it'll be easier to do simply this:

```
which_shape = raw_input("Enter shape")
shape = ['square', 'rectangle', 'triangle', 'circle', 'pentagon']

if which_shape in shape:
    print("Your entered shape is: "+which_shape)
else:
    print("Wrong shape entered.")
```

But I'm guessing your assignment requires you to actually determine which shape it was, then you gotta do it this way:

```
if which_shape in shape:
    if which_shape=="rectangle":
        ## Do something here
        pass
    elif which_shape=="triangle":
        ## Do something here
        pass
    elif which_shape=="square":
        ## Do something here
        pass
    elif which_shape=="circle":
        ## Do something here
        pass
else:
    print("Wrong shape entered")
```

Python lacks switch statements so this is how you'd make such a thing happen.

Comment: You need to change the first `elif` inside to an `if`

Comment: Thanks guys, this will help me fumble my way through